# AWS CloudWatch MetricMath Error: MetricWidget/metrics/1 should not have more than 1 item

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am new to CloudWatch MatchExpression. I’m trying to plot the percent of 5xx errors. The following is the widget I constructed in Ruby with Math expression:

```
{:title=>"5xx Errors", :view=>"timeSeries", :stacked=>false, :start=>"-P7D", :period=>300, :yAxis=>{"left"=>{:min=>0, :max=>100}}, :annotations=>{:horizontal=>[{:color=>"#ff7f00", :label=>"10", :value=>10}, {:color=>"#ff0000", :label=>"50", :value=>50}]}, :metrics=>[[{"id"=>"percent_5xx_error", "expression"=>"100*(5xx/(2xx+3xx+4xx+5xx))", "label"=>"IAD", "accountId"=>"967992492170", "region"=>"us-east-1"}], ["TangerineBox", "StatusCode2xx", "ConsoleName", "fsx-console", {"accountId"=>"967992492170", "region"=>"us-east-1", "label"=>"IAD", "id"=>"2xx", "stat"=>"Sum", "visible"=>false}], ["TangerineBox", "StatusCode3xx", "ConsoleName", "fsx-console", {"accountId"=>"967992492170", "region"=>"us-east-1", "label"=>"IAD", "id"=>"3xx", "stat"=>"Sum", "visible"=>false}], ["TangerineBox", "StatusCode4xx", "ConsoleName", "fsx-console", {"accountId"=>"967992492170", "region"=>"us-east-1", "label"=>"IAD", "id"=>"4xx", "stat"=>"Sum", "visible"=>false}], ["TangerineBox", "StatusCode5xx", "ConsoleName", "fsx-console", {"accountId"=>"967992492170", "region"=>"us-east-1", "label"=>"IAD", "id"=>"5xx", "stat"=>"Sum", "visible"=>false}]]}
```

But Its giving me the error : MetricWidget/metrics/1 should not have more than 1 item, when I try to embed the graph in wiki.

I opened up the graph is AWS CloudWatch console too and this is the following I get:

```
{
    "title": "5xx Errors",
    "view": "timeSeries",
    "stacked": false,
    "period": 300,
    "yAxis": {
        "left": {
            "min": 0,
            "max": 100
        }
    },
    "annotations": {
        "horizontal": [
            {
                "color": "#ff7f00",
                "label": "10",
                "value": 10
            },
            {
                "color": "#ff0000",
                "label": "50",
                "value": 50
            }
        ]
    },
    "metrics": [
        [ { "id": "percent_5xx_error", "expression": "100*(5xx/(2xx+3xx+4xx+5xx))", "label": "IAD", "accountId": "967992492170", "region": "us-east-1" } ],
        [ "TangerineBox", "StatusCode2xx", "ConsoleName", "fsx-console", { "accountId": "967992492170", "label": "IAD", "id": "2xx", "stat": "Sum", "visible": false } ],
        [ ".", "StatusCode3xx", ".", ".", { "accountId": "967992492170", "label": "IAD", "id": "3xx", "stat": "Sum", "visible": false } ],
        [ ".", "StatusCode4xx", ".", ".", { "accountId": "967992492170", "label": "IAD", "id": "4xx", "stat": "Sum", "visible": false } ],
        [ ".", "StatusCode5xx", ".", ".", { "accountId": "967992492170", "label": "IAD", "id": "5xx", "stat": "Sum", "visible": false } ]
    ],
    "width": 1401,
    "height": 754,
    "region": "us-east-1"
}
```

Can someone please help me to debug this issue.

Comment: So the graph works in the console, but not on the wiki? How are you embedding it in the wiki?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to look are the IDs. IDs need to start with a lower case letter. Try changing `2xx`, `3xx` ..., to something like `m2xx`, `m3xx`, ...